# Why does C blurring filter not blur corners?

Tags: c, cs50

I’ve developed a function in c in the cs50 ide to box blur a bitmap image, and at first glance it appears to blur the image. According to check50, it is not blurring corners correctly, but middle pixels and edge pixels are correct. In addition to this, I get multiple runtime errors when I run my code.

The function is supposed to loop through every pixel in the image and put the current pixel and its surrounding pixel’s RGB values into 3 arrays, red[], green[], and blue[]. If a surrounding pixel does not exist, the RGB values are not put into the color arrays.

Then, it averages out the red, green and blue values individually. It saves those values in a temporary 2d array called temp[][]. After every pixel’s average has been calculated, the image is overwritten by the color values in the temp[] array.

I thought that the logic for checking around the missing pixel was flawed, but I haven’t been able to find the problem. Also, don't understand why I would be getting runtime errors. How should I properly blur corner pixels and get rid of the runtime errors?

Here is my code:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //Define variables
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    int red[9];
    int green[9];
    int blue[9];
    int counter;
    int redavg;
    int blueavg;
    int greenavg;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            //This block of code is for the middle pixel of the 3 by 3 box
            counter = 0.00;
            red[counter] = image[j][i].rgbtRed;
            green[counter] = image[j][i].rgbtGreen;
            blue[counter] = image[j][i].rgbtBlue;
            counter++;

            //Check to see if the pixel is on the top edge
            if (i != 0)
            {
                red[counter] = image[j][i-1].rgbtRed;
                green[counter] = image[j][i-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue[counter] = image[j][i-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;

                //Checks to see if pixel is on the right edge
                if (j != width - 1)
                {
                    red[counter] = image[j+1][i-1].rgbtRed;
                    green[counter] = image[j+1][i-1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue[counter] = image[j+1][i-1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;

                    red[counter] = image[j+1][i].rgbtRed;
                    green[counter] = image[j+1][i].rgbtGreen;
                    blue[counter] = image[j+1][i].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;

                }
                //Checks to see if pixel is on the right edge
                if (j != 0)
                {
                    red[counter] = image[j-1][i-1].rgbtRed;
                    green[counter] = image[j-1][i-1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue[counter] = image[j-1][i-1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;

                    red[counter] = image[j-1][i].rgbtRed;
                    green[counter] = image[j-1][i].rgbtGreen;
                    blue[counter] = image[j-1][i].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;

                }
            }
            //Check to see if the pixel is on the bottom edge
            if (i != height - 1)
            {
                red[counter] = image[j][i+1].rgbtRed;
                green[counter] = image[j][i+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue[counter] = image[j][i+1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;

                //Checks to see if pixel is on the right edge
                if (j != width - 1)
                {
                    red[counter] = image[j+1][i+1].rgbtRed;
                    green[counter] = image[j+1][i+1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue[counter] = image[j+1][i+1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        red[counter] = image[j+1][i].rgbtRed;
                        green[counter] = image[j+1][i].rgbtGreen;
                        blue[counter] = image[j+1][i].rgbtBlue;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                //Checks to see if pixel is on the left edge
                if (j != 0)
                {
                    red[counter] = image[j-1][i+1].rgbtRed;
                    green[counter] = image[j-1][i+1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue[counter] = image[j-1][i+1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        red[counter] = image[j-1][i].rgbtRed;
                        green[counter] = image[j-1][i].rgbtGreen;
                        blue[counter] = image[j-1][i].rgbtBlue;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }

            //take red blue and green, average them, and put them into tmp array
            for (int k = 0; k < counter; k++)
            {
                redavg += red[k];
                blueavg += blue[k];
                greenavg += green[k];
            }
            redavg = round(redavg/(float)counter);
            greenavg = round(greenavg/(float)counter);
            blueavg = round(blueavg/counter);

            temp[j][i].rgbtRed = redavg;
            temp[j][i].rgbtGreen = greenavg;
            temp[j][i].rgbtBlue = blueavg;

            redavg = 0;
            blueavg = 0;
            greenavg = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < width; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < height; n++)
        {
            image[n][m].rgbtRed = temp[n][m].rgbtRed;
            image[n][m].rgbtGreen = temp[n][m].rgbtGreen;
            image[n][m].rgbtBlue = temp[n][m].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I get these runtime errors:

```
helpers.c:299:32: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:300:34: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:301:33: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:307:36: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:308:38: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:309:37: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:323:36: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:324:38: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:325:37: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
```

And check50 tells me:

```
:) blur correctly filters middle pixel
:) blur correctly filters pixel on edge
:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
    expected "70 85 95\n", not "70 136 55\n"
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 128 89\n80 ..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 135 71\n80 ..."
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Local variables in C such as `int redavg;` are not initialised, so `redavg = 0;` etc are only useful for the *next* iteration, not the one you just did. Place them earlier, *before* the summing. Generally It is poor practice to reset variables after you have used them - far easier to keep track of if you clear them before use. Aside: `counter = 0.00;` is  strange, when you defined `int counter;` This is a clue that you are *not dealing with compiler warnings*, perhaps to worse consequence in other parts of the code.

Comment: If you have a large image, there might not be enough stack for `RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];`. Use `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: The conditions for being off-edge are too complicated. There can be up to 9 pixels summed, but you have 11 pixel summing parts of the code. It needs to be simpler, perhaps with two more nested loops going from `i-1` to `i+1` and from `j-1` to `j+1`, skipping any iterations that are off-image.

Comment: ...also you don't need those 3 arrays: just sum the totals and keep count within the loop.

Comment: In lines like `red[counter] = image[j+1][...]` the index of the address will range from 1 to `height` ---> out of bounds.